# Append an array to an existing array by index value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 10060127 
    [1] => 10065127 
    [2] => 10070127 
    [3] => 10075127
)
```

I want to add an associative array based on the value in the array. e.g. find 10070127 and an an associative array to it containing various other info. Something like:

```
 [1] => 10065127 => Time : 10:00
                    Date : 16/12/2014
                    Count : 1
```

How can I recognise the correct position and push these items to this array?

Comment: $myArray[0][10065127][] = new array(); ? and then add the values?

Comment: If I don't know the position in the array of 10065127 though?

Comment: Then use `array_search` to get the key.

Comment: you can use in_array or array_search as @lolka_bolka suggested

Comment: Are the values unique? What if a value appears in an array more than once? Do you want to replace all instances or just the 1st?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$dataArray = array(
    0 => 10060127,
    1 => 10065127,
    2 => 10070127,
    3 => 10075127
);

$toAdd = array(
    1 => array(
        10065127 => array("Time" => '10:00',
            "Date" => '16/12/2014',
            "Count" => '1'
        )
    ),
    2 => array(
        10070127 => array("Time" => '17:25',
            "Date" => '11/12/2014',
            "Count" => '95'
        )
    )
);

foreach ($toAdd as $subArray) {
    $toSearch = key($subArray);
    $pos = array_search($toSearch, $dataArray);
    if ($pos !== false) {
        unset($dataArray[$pos]);
        $dataArray[$toSearch] = $subArray[$toSearch];
    }
}
var_dump ($dataArray);
```

Output will be:

```
array
  0 => int 10060127
  3 => int 10075127
  10065127 => 
    array
      'Time' => string '10:00' (length=5)
      'Date' => string '16/12/2014' (length=10)
      'Count' => string '1' (length=1)
  10070127 => 
    array
      'Time' => string '17:25' (length=5)
      'Date' => string '11/12/2014' (length=10)
      'Count' => string '95' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$id = '10070127';

$array[array_search($id, $array)] = array($id=>array(
    'time'=>'10:00',
    'Date'=>'16/12/2014',
    'Count'=>1));
```